# Nginx, AWS, EB, Docker, TCP Socket configuration 400 bad request

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services, nginx, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to let an pure TCP Socket connection on port 80 through to an Docker container on AWS also on port 80. So far i have:

- Setup the correct security groups to let port 80 through on the Load balancer, it is set to an tcp connection, not http.
- Been able to see the nginx logs on the e2c instance create by EB. The report the following:

> 172.31.22.8 - - [12/Jan/2017:20:44:43 +0000] "...data..." 400 173 "-" "-"

- And then the program creating  the socket reports:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
> Server: nginx/1.10.1
> Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 21:05:54 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html
> Content-Length: 173
> Connection: close
>
> <html>
> <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
> <body bgcolor="white">
> <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
> <hr><center>nginx/1.10.1</center>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

I have tried many different nginx configurations.But **at default**, before I began the configs was as follows:

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
# Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    log_format  healthd '$msec"$uri"$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"$http_x_forwarded_for';

    include       /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include       /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-upstream.conf**

```
upstream docker {
        server 172.17.0.3:80;
        keepalive 256;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass            http://docker;
        proxy_http_version    1.1;

        proxy_set_header    Connection            $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade                $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I know the Loadbalancer is working because the data reaches the nginx e2c instance that runs docker. But nginx does not forward the request to the docker container. Yes there is an application running on port 80 of the container, it is a C socket bound to 0.0.0.0 on port 80. So no HTTTP correct? it is  TCP?

So my question, what must the configuration file be for nginx to forward TCP socket connection to the docker container??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It has been about 10 months since I posted this. AWS no has something called a Network Load Balancer. I have not tried it out, but think it should allow pure TCP sockets with sticky sessions. So I am closing this for now until I try that.